# Handling inner changes of class in collection

Tags: c#, litedb

I don’t know how to explain it correctly, but I have a collection of classes:

```
using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db")) {
var _collection = db.GetCollection<TestClass>("mycollection");
}


public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass() {
        Task.Run(() => {
                     SomeProperty = ...; //Request to update value from outside
                 });
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

As you can see, a class changes its properties after instantiation from the inside.

How, after changing a property, save it back to the database, but with a new property?

---

P.S. If I didn’t explain the question well enough or chose the wrong path initially - write about it

Comment: Did you mean how change your Entity class structure after already insert data with old structure?

Comment: @mbdavid yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to modify your existing data when you change your entity class is use `BsonDocument` abstract document model. Using `BsonDocument` you can change fields as string and implement rules to update your model, like this:

```
public LiteDatabase OpenDatabase()
{
    var db = new LiteDatabase("data.db");

    // check for database version
    if (db.UserVersion == 0)
    {
        var col = db.GetCollection("mycollection");

        foreach(var doc in col.FindAll())
        {
            doc["NewProperty"] = doc["OldProperty"];

            doc.RemoveKey("OldProperty");

            col.Update(doc);
        }

        db.UserVersion = 1;
    }

    return db;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mbdavid. But how do I make UserVersion to 1 for all the newly (self) created database? So it won't have to go through the adjustment since the above-suggested code deal with an existing database.